# Проблема с скачиванием файла

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, реактивное-программирование

Добый день.

Я пишу демо приложении на `Spring WebFlux` + `Thymeleaf`. 
Тут есть два метода:

- сохранить картину
- и потом скачать её.

Сохранине проходит успешно, но при попытке скачивания возникает ошибка и файл не может быть найден

Вот мой сервис

```
@Service
public class FileService {

    private final String path = "./src/main/resources/upload/";
    private final FileRepository fileRepository;
    private final Path basePath = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/upload/");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public FileService(FileRepository fileRepository) {
        this.fileRepository = fileRepository;
    }


    public Mono<Void> upload(String name, Mono<FilePart> filePartMono){
        return filePartMono
                .flatMap(fp -> {
                    FileEntity items = mapper.convertValue(new FileEntity(fp.filename(), basePath + fp.filename()), FileEntity.class);
                   items.setName(name);
                   items.setPath(String.valueOf(basePath));
                    return fileRepository.save(items).then(Mono.just(fp));
                })
                .flatMap(fp -> fp.transferTo(basePath.resolve(fp.filename())))
                .then();
    }

    public Mono<Void> download(String name, ServerHttpResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = String.valueOf(getFileName(name));
        ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage zeroCopyResponse = (ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage) response;
        response.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "");
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(path + fileName);
        return zeroCopyResponse.writeWith(file, 0, file.length());
    }



    Mono<FileEntity> getFileName(String name) throws RuntimeException {
        return fileRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
private final FileService fileService;

    public UploadController(FileService fileService) {
        this.fileService = fileService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "file/single", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<Void> uploadV2(@RequestPart("user-name") String name ,@RequestPart("fileToUpload") Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        return fileService.upload(name , filePartMono);
    }

    @GetMapping("file/single")
    public String uploadPage() {
        return "upload";
    }


    @GetMapping("/download/file/one")
    public Mono<Void> downloadFileOne(@RequestParam("token") String token,
                                   ServerHttpResponse response ) throws IOException {
        return fileService.download(token, response);
    }

    @GetMapping("/download/file")
    public String dowloadFile() {
        return "dowload";
    }
```

Так же можете предложить какие нибудь варианты? Я новичок пока оссобо не шарю

Comment: приложите скрин директории `src/main/resources/upload`. приложите то что сохраняется в базу (имена и пути сущностей)

Comment: я добавил ваш метод скачивания, вбил туда корректные данные - и все скачалось. Поэтому есть версия, что с загрузкой как раз таки непорядок. Поэтому приложите то что я просил выше (данные в папке, данные из базы)

Comment: используйте абсолютные пути до директорий, задавайте их через application.yaml, напишите тесты на методы `upload` и `download`, примеров в сети полно, вот пример как скачать статичную картинку https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file